# I want to use the variable outside the subscribe parameter

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4

I'm using Ionic 4 and I want to use the variable everywhere on the file. It usage is important for me.

I'm using a firebase and I want to pass one variable of one page to another page. This problem is solved. But I want to use that variable on every part of second page.

```
//first page code
joinRoom(key) {
   this.router.navigate(['chat', {key: key}]);
}

//second page code
constructor(public activateroute: ActivatedRoute){
   this.activateroute.params.subscribe((data: any) => {
     console.log(data);
     this.key = data.key;
  });
}
```

I want to use `this.key` everywhere on .ts page like on other functions and I want to declare it globally on page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach of making a global variable is to assign it onto window, instead of `this.key = data.key` you´d have `window.key = data.key`

However that approach is more of a hack than a real solution

A better solution would be to have some sort of singleton key/value registry that you can then inject into every component you need

```
constructor(public activateroute: ActivatedRoute, private configRegistry: CustomRegistry){
   this.activateroute.params.subscribe((data: any) => {
     console.log(data);

     // this.key = data.key;
     configRegistry.set('key', data.key);
  });
}

elsewhere in another file
constructor(private configRegistry: CustomRegistry){
   console.log(configRegistry.get('key'));
}
```